# Der Unterschied zwischen einem Adverb und einem Satzadjektiv

Tags: adjective, adverb

In meinem Grammatiklehrbuch im Abschnitt über Satzadjektive (nicht normale Adjektive) gibt es folgendes Beispiel:

- "Ich bedanke mich *umständlich*."

Jedoch gibt [diese Seite](https://www.schulminator.com/deutsch/adverb) folgendes Beispiel für Adverben:

- "Der Held *kämpft tapfer*."

Meiner Meinung nach sollte also im ersten Beispiel das "umständlich" ein Adverb sein. Wo bin ich hier falsch? Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Satzadjektiven und Adverben?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was ein Satzadjektiv ist, ist [auf der Webseite des Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Satzadjektiv) erklärt:

Ein Adjektiv, das nicht ein Verb beschreibt, sondern ein eigener Satzteil ist.

Als ein Beispiel ist der Satz:

> Er hält sie für **klug**.

... angegeben; das Wort "*klug*" ist in diesem Fall kein Adverb, denn es beschreibt nicht das Verb "*halten*".

Im folgenden Satz wäre "*leicht*" ein Adverb und "*klug*" ein Satzadjektiv.

> Man kann sie **leicht** für **klug** halten.

... denn das Adverb (bzw. das als Adverb verwendete Adjektiv?) "*leicht*" beschreibt das Verb "*halten*" genauer, während es sich beim Satzadjektiv "*klug*" nicht um eine genauere Beschreibung des Verbs "*halten*" handelt.

> In meinem Grammatiklehrbuch im Abschnitt über Satzadjektive (nicht normale Adjektive) gibt es folgendes Beispiel:
>
> "Ich bedanke mich umständlich."

Ich bin kein Germanist, glaube aber, dass es sich hier um einen Fehler im Grammatiklehrbuch handelt:

Wenn ich Satzadjektive richtig verstanden habe, haben sie in einem Satz bestimmte Funktion, während Adverbien lediglich das Verb genauer beschreiben. Man kann ein Adverb also einfach weglassen, ohne dass sich der Sinn des Satzes grundlegend ändert.

Das geht bei einem Satzadjektiv nicht:

> Ich finde sie.  (... nachdem ich nach ihr gesucht habe.)
>   Ich finde sie hässlich.  (... während Andere sie für hübsch halten.)

Beim Satz:

> Ich bedanke mich umständlich.

... kann ich das Wort "*umständlich*" jedoch einfach so weglassen, ohne dass sich der Sinn des Satzes grundlegend ändert.

Das ist für mich ein Indikator, dass es sich nicht um ein Satzadjektiv handeln kann.

Es ist allerdings durchaus möglich, dass es eine Redewendung "*sich umständlich bedanken*" gibt, die ich nicht kenne und die etwas ganz anderes bedeutet als "*sich bedanken*". In diesem Fall wäre das Wort "*umständlich*" eventuell ein Satzadjektiv.

P.S.: Wenn ein Satz verschiedene Bedeutungen haben kann, kann ein Wort je nach Bedeutung einmal ein Satzadjektiv und einmal ein Adverb sein:

> Ich hatte meinen Laptop verloren. *Aber ich fand ihn **schnell**.*
>
> Mein Freund hielt meinen Laptop für langsam. *Aber ich fand ihn **schnell**.*

Comment: Du schreibst: *»Im folgenden Satz wäre "leicht" ein Adverb«* Das ist falsch. Das Wort »leicht« ist immer und in jedem Satz ein Adjektiv, denn »Adjektiv« ist der Name der Wortart, zu der das Wort »leicht« gehört, und die Wortart ist unabhängig von jeder grammatischen Funktion.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Aus diesem Grund habe ich nach dem Beispiel noch einmal "das als Adverb verwendete Adjektiv" geschrieben. Das Wort "tapfer" aus dem Beispiel des Fragestellers ist schließlich auch ein Adjektiv, das als Adverb verwendet wird und kein echtes Adverb.

Answer (score -1):

### Adverb

Das ist eine Wortart, also eine Eigenschaft, die ein Wort unabhängig vom grammatischen Gebrauch hat, also z.B. auch wenn es in einem Wörterbuch aufgelistet ist.

Adverbien haben Ähnlichkeiten mit Adjektiven, unterscheiden sich von ihnen aber dadurch, dass sie nicht als Attribut eines Substantivs verwendet werden können. Adverbien können auch nicht gebeugt oder gesteigert werden.

Die Wörter aus der Frage und auch als Martins Antwort sind allesamt keine Adverbien, sondern Adjektive:

- Attribut eines Substantivs, und zugleich Beispiele für Beugungen:

  > **umständlich** - ein umständlich**es** Manöver
  >   **tapfer** - ein tapfer**er** Held
  >   **klug** - ein klug**es** Kind
  >   **leicht** - eine leicht**e** Beute
  >   **hässlich** - ein hässlich**es** Entlein
  >   **schnell** - ein schnell**es** Auto
- Steigerung (hier nur zwei Beispiele; alle oben genannten Adjektive können gesteigert werden):

  > umständlich, umständlicher, am umständlichsten
  >   tapfer, tapferer, am tapfersten

<sup>*Anmerkung: Es gibt auch viele Adjektive, die man nicht steigern kann, z.B. »gleich«, »dreieckig« oder »leer«*</sup>

Selbstverständlich können Adjektive in einem Satz nicht nur als Attribute verwendet werden, sondern auch als Adverbiale, das wurde sowohl in der Frage als auch in Martins Antwort auch ausgiebig gezeigt. Aber ein Adverbial ist etwas anderes als ein Adverb.

- **Adverb**
  Eine Wortart. Die Wortart kann man in einem guten Wörterbuch für jedes einzelne Wort nachschlagen.
- **Adverbial**
  Eine grammatische Funktion, die sich aus dem konkreten Gebrauch in einem Satz ergibt. Ob ein Wort als Adverbial verwendet wird, kann man nicht in einem Wörterbuch nachschlagen. Dazu muss man den Satz, in den das Wort vorkommt, analysieren.

Adverbien sind hingegen diese Wörter:

- heute, morgen, morgens, abends, dort, hinten, gern, ...

Diese Wörter können nicht gebeugt und nicht gesteigert werden, und sie können nicht als Attribute von Substantiven verwendet werden.

<sup>*Anmerkung: Es gibt unter den Adverbien fünf Ausnahmen, die doch gesteigert werden können, z.B. »gern - lieber - am liebsten« oder »bald - eher - am ehesten«*</sup>

---

### Satzadjektiv

Das ist ein sehr unglücklich gewählter Begriff, der eigentlich zwei grammatische Verwendungsformen von Adjektiven unter einem Namen zusammenfasst. Jedenfalls ist »Satzadjektiv« keine Wortart (man kann nicht im Wörterbuch nachschauen, ob ein Wort ein Satzadjektiv ist), sondern, wie gerade erwähnt, eine grammatische Funktion (man muss einen Satz analysieren).

Adjektive kann man auf drei verschiedene Arten verwenden, zwei davon habe ich oben schon erwähnt:

- **Attribut**
  Wenn ein Adjektiv als Attribut verwendet wird, steht es in gebeugter Form gemeinsam mit einem Substantiv in einer Nominalgruppe und beschreibt eine Eigenschaft der Sache, die von diesem Substantiv benannt wird.

  > Das ***rote*** Auto steht in der Garage.
  >   Der Kapitän vollführte ein ***umständliches*** Manöver.
  >   Der König sah den ***tapferen*** Helden.
- **Prädikativ**
  In dieser Verwendung ist das Adjektiv ein Teil des Prädikats, wobei das Verb eine Kolupa ist. (Kopula sind z.B. *sein, werden, bleiben, ...*)
  Das Adjektiv beschreibt auch hier eine Eigenschaft eines Substantivs, aber nicht als Teil der Nominalgruppe in der das Substantiv steht, sondern als Teil des Prädikats.

  > Ihre Wangen wurden **rot.**
  >   Das Manöver erschien allen Beobachtern **umständlich.**
  >   Der Held blieb **tapfer.**
- **Adverbial**
  Auf diese Art können nicht nur Adjektive verwendet werden, sondern auch Adverbien. Beide Wortarten beschreiben in dieser Verwendungsart eine Eigenschaft des Verbs, also keine Eigenschaft eines Substantivs:

  - Adjektive als Adverbiale:

    > Das Auto *fuhr **schnell.***
    >   Jürgen *griff **umständlich*** zum Glas und stieß es dabei um.
    >   Georg *trat* dem Drachen ***tapfer*** entgegen.
  - Adverbien als Adverbiale:

    > Das Auto *fuhr **gestern.***
    >   Jürgen *griff **oft*** zum Glas.
    >   Georg *trat* dem Drachen ***gern*** entgegen.

**Satzadjektiv**
Die beiden Adjektiv-Verwendungsformen *Prädikativ* und *Adverbial* werden manchmal zum Begriff *Satzadjektiv* zusammengefasst. Sie haben gemeinsam, dass das Adjektiv ungebeugt bleibt und nicht als Teil einer Nominalgruppe auftritt.

Der Begriff hat nicht nur den Nachteil, dass er zwei verschiedene Verwendungsarten zusammenfasst. Er schließt dabei aus einer der beiden Verwendungsarten auch einen Teil aus, nämlich die adverbial verwendeten Adverbien.

- *»Anna ist **schön**«.*
  Wortart: Adjektiv
  Grammatische Funktion: Prädikativ, Satzadjektiv
- *»Das Auto fährt **schnell**«.*
  Wortart: Adjektiv
  Grammatische Funktion: Adverbial, Satzadjektiv
- *»Otto kommt **morgen**«.*
  Wortart: Adverb
  Grammatische Funktion: Adverbial, aber kein Satzadjektiv